# How to find an element with the minimum number of steps

Tags: python, algorithm

How can I count the minimum steps to get to a specific index counting forward and backward?

The list is:

```
content = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If I start from index `0` and want to know how many steps to get to the number `4` iterating forwards I'll get `3`, because:

```py
#0 #1 #2 #3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But I also want to know it backward, like:

```
#0       #2 #1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In the example above the minimum amount of steps is `2`

Another example

```py
content = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
start_index = 4 # "E"
to_find = "D"

 #1   #2   #3   #4   #0
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
# Moving forward I'll start from "A" again until reache "D"

                #1   #0
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] # Moving backwards...
```

In the example above the minimum amount of steps is `1`

Note: the target element is unique.

Comment: Simply decrement your index instead of incrementing it. Python lists support negative indexing

Comment: I don't understand how the problem involves *counting* or explicitly iterating. You know how to ask Python where the `4` is in the list (its index), right? If you are starting from index 0, can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you the distance to the other index?

Comment: This question is really confusing. Is your list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`? Also, Are you searching for `2` like the last example, or `4` as in the second?

Comment: @Mark I'm trying to know the minimum steps to get to `4`

Comment: @RafaAcioly the element you're trying to find in the list is unique? Or duplicates exist?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur yes, they are unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that this is a modulus problem:

```
content = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
start_index = 4 # "E"
to_find = "D"

length = len(content)

difference = content.index(to_find) - start_index

print(min(difference % length, -difference % length))
```

Note that we only search `content` *once*, unlike some solutions, including the currently accepted one, which search `content` *twice*!

Comment: This is basically the same as my answer. I didn't use the modulus operator but the idea is the same.

Comment: @Olivier, I came at this from a modular aproach, first checking whether `math.fmod()` alone would give me what I wanted when `%` didn't (the two vary when it comes to negative numbers) but finally settled on the above.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```py
len(content) - content.index(4)
```

Because `content.index(4)` finds the "forward" index, and then the "backward" index equals the number of elements from the element `4` to the end of the list, which is the same as all of them minus the first `content.index(4)`.

As noted in the comments, this finds the index of the *first* occurrence in the list.
In order to find that of the last (i.e. first from the end), you might do:

```py
content[::-1].index(4) + 1
```

Example:

```py
>>> content = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']
>>> len(content) - content.index('b')
3
>>> content[::-1].index('b') + 1
1
```

Comment: I believe there is a risk in this option → in case there is more than one value 4 in the list, it will return according to the first and not the last. I think it might be interesting to increase the answer by warning about this!

Comment: Give then OP's input this would return `3` when searching for the value `2`. But in that case the forward search is shorter.

Comment: @Mark No, it would return `4`: `len(content) - content.index(2) = 5 - 1 = 4`.

Comment: @Anakhand — the question is pretty unclear. It looks like you answered the question title. The body of the question seems to involve finding a minimum.

Comment: @Anakhand I just add another example

Answer (score 1):

```
def minimal_steps(lst: list, num: int, start: int = 0):
    pos = lst.index(num)
    return min(abs(pos - start), len(lst) - abs(pos - start))
```

EDIT: update answer since the question updated.

Comment: Maybe not.  Your parameters don't match the variables in your function so the code doesn't run.  Even if I fix that, it doesn't appear to get the OP's first example correct (off by 1).

Answer (score 1):

No `for` loops solution:

```
content = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
start_index = 4 # "E"
to_find = "D"

c2 = content*2
forward = c2[start_index:].index(to_find)
backward = c2[::-1][len(content)-start_index-1:].index(to_find)

print('minimum steps:', min(forward, backward))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the target element is always present in the array:

```
content = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
start_index = 4 # "E"
to_find = "D"

end_index = content.index(to_find)
d = end_index - start_index
forward  = d if d>=0 else len(content) + d
backward = -d if d<=0 else len(content) - d
print(min(forward, backward))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method that offsets the list first and uses the start `list.index()` method:

```
content = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
start_index = 0
to_find = 4

temp = content[start_index:] + content[:start_index]

print(temp.index(to_find))           # Forward
print(temp[::-1].index(to_find) + 1) # Backward
```

Output:

```
3
2
```

For example #2:

```
content = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
start_index = 4
to_find = "D"

temp = content[start_index:] + content[:start_index]

print(temp.index(to_find))           # Forward
print(temp[::-1].index(to_find) + 1) # Backward
```

Output:

```
4
1
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply decrement your index instead of incrementing it. Python lists support negative indexing

```
content = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
end_element = 4

i = 0
count = 0
while content[i] != end_element:
    i -= 1 
    count += 1

print(count) # 2
```

Of course, this leaves the possibility of an `IndexError: list index out of range` when the `end_element` is not in your list, but you can handle that error pretty easily.